# Decomposing the average squared distance between X and E(X|Y)

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

I'm trying to split: $l = E[(X-E(X|Y))^2] $ into an expression of the form:
$$1-corr(X,Y)^2 - E[?]$$
Were I need to find the ? in the expectation above. $X,Y$ have mean 0 and variance 1.
I'm given a hint: to let $z = -\tfrac{Cov(X,Y)}{Var(Y)}$  and start with $$E[(X+zY -zY - E(X|Y))^2]$$
I'm lost because expanding the argument of the expectation doesn't lead me anywhere and the $z$ terms just cancel out. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E[X|Y]:=g(Y),$ and $\rho=\text{corr}(X,Y).$ Then
$$E[ (X-g(Y))^2]=\underbrace{E[X^2]}_{=1}+E[g(Y)^2-2Xg(Y)]\\
=1-\rho^2-E[-\rho^2-g(Y)^2+2Xg(Y)].
$$

Not sure of the significance though...